# achieving a fluid picture grid, with different heights of rows

Tags: html, css

I'm having troubles achieving my designers goal of a fluid picture grid, but based on rows of equally high pictures, not columns of equal width which everyone seems to be so fond off.

here's he design:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7187819/Capture.PNG

here's the point where i got stuck:
http://jsfiddle.net/EwTjD/1/

my goal is a fluid picture-grid that scales with the map next to it when you resize the browser.

I tried background-image first, but that got me stuck with a height that didn't scale. And to be able to use `transform` i got to use `position:absolute`, which messes up my floating img's...

any help? :)

ps: this should be achieved without Javascript

Answer (score 0):

im going to start charging for doing peoples work. lol.

you need to set static heights if you want them to line up horizontally.

in your design example, those pictures sizes where carefully calculated. u need to take into account the amount of padding, add up how much padding space will be used, and then subtract that from the total amount of space u got. then u can divide that amongst the images

Comment: uhu, i achieved that, the problem is that it has to be responsive, the whole block of images needs to scale with the map next to it. with a fixed height they just narrow down in width, which just hurts my eyes...

Comment: ok so why don't you play with percentages? like margin-bottom:1%;and then each image height:48%. or something like that

Comment: i achieved it through padding-top on the parent container, and a negative margin on the img. then some transform:scale magic, topped off with some height:%

i'll post the code next Monday, forgot to save to cloud for the weekend

Comment: great so the percentages worked i assume? glad you figured it out. kudos

Comment: not really no, percentages alone didn't do the trick. Because the img are floating the parent div's collapse when i use percentages for height. 
Had to use padding in percentage on the parent div to create a height and prevent collapse, then negative margins to get the picture up in the div (the padding pushed it down). The height in percentage is solely used to make the image scale according to the parent div.